# How would you parse this String to an object?

Tags: java, html, dom

Note that this question is not about implementation, but for programming tips.

I'm trying to read some HTML code, and then create an object / several objects in order to paint it back again chaning the format.

For example. Imagine this html:

```
<body>
Hello, this is some plain and I'm going to attach an image.
<img src="someimage.jpg" />
And after the image I keep writting.

And as this is a forum message, you can add a div to quote like the following:
<div class="post-quote"> Some user said something</div>

And that was it!
</body>
```

As you can see, there are several elements, like `<img>` and `<div>`.

My overall goal, is to have everything split up like:

- Text
- Image
- Text
- Div(quote class)
- Text

And then, programming specific, it could be a `List` of `contentElements`.
With this list, I could paint those elements back into the screen customly formatted and positioned.

However, I can't find out how to divide the HTML String using some logical method.

Do you guys have any tips? How would you split this String to achieve the previously explained issue?

Thanks!!

Questions are welcome!

**Edit**
JSOUP is a parser. I'm not looking for a parser. I'm looking for TIPS about how can I keep the order of the parsed elements. Reread my question, please!

Comment: use an html parser like http://jsoup.org/?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a HTML parser such as [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Example on your HTML:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

print(doc.select("img").attr("src"));       ==> someimage.jpg
print(doc.select("div.post-quote").text()); ==> Some user said something
```

Comment: With this, I can extract the divs and things, which I'm already doing. But how do you "keep" them in order? Reread my question, please :D

Comment: Read the jsoup documentation. It is explained briefly there. http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation

Comment: I can't find what you said.